# Flutter - How to change the visibility of a single widget in a widget list?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I pull some variables in Firebase and I create a widget list with these variables. I want to control widget visibility when I click a widget. When I use the `Visibility` widget and set "visible: widgetVisibility" value, all widgets are changed at the same time. I only want the widget I clicked to change. How can I do that?

```
body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: _keyService.getKeys(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return !snapshot.hasData
              ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
              : ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    DocumentSnapshot mypost = snapshot.data!.docs[index];

                    return Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(size * 0.3),
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          valueVisible = !valueVisible;
                        },
                  
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: ColorItems.mainColor,
                              border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.grey),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(size),
                            child: Container(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: Text(
                                      "${mypost['key']}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  const Text(
                                    ": ",
                                    style:
                                        TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 20,
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      child: Visibility(
                                    visible: valueVisible,
                                    child: Text(
                                      "${mypost['value']}",
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
        })
```

Additionally, screenshots is here..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using statefullWidget also for list, create a separate List<int> to control all widget visbility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the optimal solution, but I always create a List for that purpose:

instead of one valueVisible bool I create a List and add a bool for each item in the list.

```
...itemBuilder: (context, index) { valueVisibleList.add(true)...
```

and in the button I then use the current item index to change only the corresponding bool

```
 onTap: () { setState(({ 
               valueVisibleList[index] = !valueVisibleList[index];
               })
             },
```

Comment: I tried this first, it's very practical and works well. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `Map<String, bool>` where the keys are the post's key and the value its visibility. The visibility should default to `true` if the key is not present. And the state should only change inside a `setState` function.

It would be something like the following (Check out the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=1471130210bca271d0cc3c48f97b4147)):

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

final posts = [
  for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {'key': 'key$i', 'value': '$i'}
];

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final valueVisible = <String, bool>{};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const size = 16.0;

    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: posts.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final mypost = posts[index];

          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(size * 0.3),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  valueVisible[mypost['key']!] =
                      !(valueVisible[mypost['key']!] ?? true);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xffff9400),
                    border: Border.all(width: 5, color: Colors.grey),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(size),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          "${mypost['key']}",
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 24,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        ": ",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 24,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Visibility(
                          visible: valueVisible[mypost['key']!] ?? true,
                          child: Text(
                            "${mypost['value']}",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 24,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: After above solution I tried to implement this as well. It works pretty well. Thanks for your efforts :)